# В чём различие?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На ютубе во многих образовательных видеоуроках rb.velocity вставляют то просто в Start, то в Update. В чём различие? Если нужно только один раз задать объекту rb.velocity, чтобы объект просто вправо двигался, можно же просто первый код использовать? Update же только будет нагружать игру. Или Update нужен с rb.velocity?

1.

```
private void Start()
{
   rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
   rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
}
```

2. 

```
private void Start()
{
   rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
}

private void Update() or private void FixedUpdate()
{
   rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
}
```

Comment: А тебе что нужно? Постоянно задавать скорость или единоразово ее задать? Используй то, что тебе нужно исходя из контекста задачи. Всё взаимодействие с физикой происходит в FixedUpdate в обычном апдейте этого делать не надо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница огромная. Если ты видишь `GetComponent` в `Update`, закрывай это видео, человек не умеет код писать. Всяких гошь дударей в интернетах как грязи.

А вообще код должен выглядеть так:

```
// обязует иметь компонент тела, делая ошибку отсутствия не возможной
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public полей не должно существовать
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 1;
    // то с чем постоянно работают кешируют в поля класса, что-бы не тратить ресурсы
    private Rigidbody2D _body;

    // движение и инпуты это разные ответственности, поэтому их должен посылать
    // кто-то снаружи, для этого используются свойства, а не публичные поля
    // то есть персонаж и враг могут двигаться одним и тем-же скриптом, а команды даются разными
    public float HorizontalInput { get; set; }

    public float Speed => _speed;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // с тем что касается физики тел, работают в FixedUpdate 
    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        _body.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalInput*_speed, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно уточнить я уже давно такое видел [SerializeField] private, но не мог понять. Почему [SerializeField] private лучше использовать, чем public?

Comment: Потому что это подрузамевает установление значение ТОЛЬКО через испектор и НИКАК иначе. Если она должно быть видимо снаружи но не изменяемо пишется еще `get` свойство через лямда выражение `=>`.

Comment: Понял, Спасибо!